# Automatically change instance tier, good practice?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

It is a good practice to automatically change the instance tier of a CloudSQL database? For example, using a cheaper tier during the nights when there is less demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing tier is a non-trivial operation.

1. If you are using first generation, it will cause a restart, this causes downtime and the instance will start with a cold buffer pool.
2. If you are using second generation, the entire GCE instance backing your cloud sql instance will be rebuilt, it will take even longer than the first generation.

Overall, I don't recommend doing this just to save cost.